# Indentation is invalid on vim-8.0.1763 with `set autoindent`

Tags: vim, indentation, vim-plugin

I have the following in my `$HOME/.vimrc` :

```
set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

However when I open `C` file, it seems indentation does not work, e.g.

```
int func(int a)
{ ...

Here I push ENTER after `{` but the cursor goes on the next line under `{`
```

I expect to have a cursor indented by 4 on the next line. If I `set cindent`, then it works as expected, but is it the right way? How do I make sure that indentation still works with other source files, e.g. `python` ?

Thanks.

Comment: What OS? What version of vim?

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23135/auto-back-indent-word-else-in-if-else-statement-in-vim)